# Usage of "However" instead of "while"

Tags: discourse-markers, however-placement

Can I rephrase the following sentence with "however"?

> While application development approaches abound in the software world, the evaluation of the existing programming frameworks tend to focus  on specific application context.

sentence rephrased:

> The application development approaches abound in the software world. However, the evaluation of the existing programming frameworks tend to focus on specific application context.

Comment: Off topic (request for rewrite/critique).

Comment: Why do you want to rephrase it? I mean, you could, but what is the reason for wanting to?

Comment: @MετάEd What an unseasonably friendly thing to say! Or maybe I mean vice versa.

Comment: Read the FAQ (http://english.stackexchange.com/faq), read the past Q&A to know what kind of questions are dealt with on ELU. Check out writersSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with including the definite article at the beginning of the second example. Better would be

> Application development approaches abound in the software world. However, the evaluation of the existing programming frameworks tend to focus on specific application context.

Arguably, even better would be

> Application development approaches abound in the software world; however, evaluation of the existing programming frameworks tends to focus on specific application context.

Notice the second *the* removed and the switch in number of the verb *tend* to *tends*.

Comment: I think we're just getting suckered into providing a proofreading service here. OP is only actually asking about whether it's better to use *"While A, B"* or *"A. However B"*. **While** my answer would be "It's just a stylistic choice", I notice you've chosen to cast both your rephrasings using the other option. That's not unreasonable. **However**, I doubt you actually meant to endorse one at the expense of the other.